# Как решить проблему ловли ошибок в Чистой Архитектуре?

Tags: архитектура, теория, обработка-ошибок

Есть вью со списком. Есть фича добавления элемента в список с сохранением его в локальную бд(типа кэш) и сервер. Я написал целую цепочку, которая происходит.

1. ловим событие во вью
2. делаем валидацию вводных данных в презентере
3. конвертируем уи модель в апп модель в презентере
4. передаем данные в интерактор через вызов метода AddItemUseCase
5. в этом кейсе вызываем метод репозитория "сохранить в БД"
6. в методе репозитория данные конвертируются в БД модель и сохраняются
7. в кейсе вызываем метод "отправить на сервер" репозитория
8. в методе репозитория конвертируем в Нетворк модель и отправляем
9. получаем удачный результат в виде Нетворк модели
10. конвертируем в апп модель
11. отправляем в интерактор этот результат
12. отправляем с интерактора в презентер
13. конвертируем их в УИ модель
14. кормим результат вью (сообщение там или я хз)

Вот цепочка показывает вариант того, что все отработало чётко. То-есть у нас нет никаких  ошибок и все супер. А если у нас что-то упало на любом этапе? На этапе валидацми, к примеру. Или на этапе сохранения на сервер(потеряли подключение)? Причём мы наверное хотим обрабатывать все эти результаты по разному. Если валидация не прошла, то просто сообщение, если  сети нет, то ... сделать две попытки, и заблочить уи до момента ответа. Есть смысл разложить это все в отдельный слой exception, который бы занимался фоновой(асинхронной) обработкой ошибок? Так например потеря связи вызывает ошибку, которая отдаётся этому слою, а он автоматически блокирует(хз как) все ЮзКейсы где нужен интернет, автоматически отправляю в уи сообщение об ошибке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Подразумевается вариант под **Android**)

Не знаю как в идеальном **Clean**, но у меня так:

Во **View** (например бейзАктивити) есть метод, который ловит любые ошибки:

```
void handleException(Throwable throwable);
```

В него может попасть мой кастомный иксепшин:

```
//Упрощенная версия без подробностей
public class SimpleException extends RuntimeException {

    protected @StringRes int textResId;
    protected String text;

}
```

Одновременно используется только одно поле для текста, **View** само разберется, какой из них 'not null'. Есть и другие поля, про них упомяну в конце ответа.

Для генерации исключений в других слоях использую:

1) Операторы условия, например в каком-нибудь **репозитории**:

```
if(!response.isSuccess()) {
   throw new SimpleException(response.getStringОшибкаОтСервера())
}
```

2) Операторы RxJava, например:

```
.onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
    if(ошибка instanceOf НапримерНетворкИксепшин) {
       throw new SimpleException(R.string.все_очень_плохо)
    } else {
       // + другие проверки, если ничего не нашли, то отдаем оригинальный иксепшин дальше
       // P.S. вместо Single может быть другой Обсервабл
       return Single.error(throwable); 
});
```

Пример подписки в **презентере**:

```
.subscribe(
        response -> {
            //...
        },
        throwable -> {
            // Логика специфичная данному кейсу, доп. проверки и т.д.
            if (instanceOf ...){}

            // Обязательная
            getView().handleException(throwable);
        })
```

Пример обработчика во **View**:

```
@Override
public void handleException(Throwable throwable) {
    if (throwable instanceof SimpleException) {
        // show Error: ((SimpleException) throwable).getText();
    } else if (throwable instanceof ЧтоНибудьЕще) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // Неизвестная ошибка!
        // show Error: R.string.error_unknown_error
    }
}
```

Как упоминалось выше, некоторые "штуки" были упрощены, Настоящий, расширенный вариант:

Модель SimpleException так же содержит поле "тип ошибки"

```
public enum SimpleErrorType {

    /**
     * Критическая, продолжать Кейс нельзя.
     */
    FATAL,

    /**
     * Замечание, можно продолжать Кейс.
     */
    WARNING

}
```

Тип выбирается в зависимости от контекста ошибки, и чаще всего, передается в конструкторе. Как видно из описания, возможны следующие сценарии:

1. Критический, когда нужно прервать кейс, например для регистрации не загрузилась инфа для обязательного поля, юзер как бы может заполнять другие поля, но при "попытке" зарегистрироваться все равно увидит ошибку, лучше сразу "показать", что ничего не выйдет.
2. Не критический, например "пароли не совпадают". В этом случае юзер может все исправить, и можно обойтись замечанием типа снекбара или setError у инпутПоля.

Что касается метода *handleException(Throwable throwable);*, то он на самом деле выглядит так:

```
public void handleException(Throwable throwable, View.OnClickListener retryAction, View.OnClickListener cancelAction);
```

Два новых аргумента служат для интерактива. Юзеру предлагается два действия:

1. Повторить попытку.
2. Отменить действие.

**View** само решает как это отобразить(диалогом, снекбаром, фулскрин заглушкой и т.д). Обработчики могут быть **Nullable**, т.е. можно вывести только одно из действий или вообще не показывать их. Так же текст для действий может быть кастомизируемым (с помощью доп. аргументов в методе или доп. полей в **SimpleException**). Все зависит от потребностей\реализации.

Comment: Идея мне понятно, спасибо. Но все равно, мне не нравится ваш подход к архитектуре, так-как у вас вью принимает решение о том, как отобразить ошибку, что, насколько мне известно, должен делать презентер. + у вас ошибку генерирует репозиторий, что тоже не отвечает на мой вопрос полностью, так-как ошибка может быть сгенерирована в интеракторе во время выполнения алгоритмов бизнес-логики. Но спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Мне хотелось бы выдвинуть два принципиально разных подхода, один из которых был описан товарищем Senya.dev:

1. Вы действительно делаете несколько различных типов исключений, а потом обрабатываете их в View в блоке с большим количеством проверок типа (instanceof). Рассмотрим минусы данного подхода:

   - Нигде нет гарантии, что вы вдруг не забудете о каком-то типе исключений. То есть, конечного списка у вас нет и вы можете надеяться только на свою память и //TODO
   - Информация в исключения может писаться любая, и нет гарантии что туда не попадет null и -100500 одновременно, что приведет к печальным последствиям
2. Альтернативой первому варианту может послужить следующий подход: следует завести один класс унаследованный от Exception/Throwable, который в дальнейшем будет использоваться в качестве контейнера. Далее, завести enum для всех типов источников с абстрактным методом для получения экземпляра класса-контракта, по которому наш контейнер будет заполняться и по которому же мы будем в блоке обработки получаться информацию о возникшем исключении. Далее следует лишь завести поле, которое является данным enum-ом в контейнере и определить методы для заполнения/получения данных из него по ключам.

Пример enum-идентификатора источника исключения:

```
public enum Reason {

    VALIDATION {
        @Override
        public ValidationExceptionContract getContract() {
            return new ValidationExceptionContract();
        }
    };

    public abstract <T extends ContractAccessor> T getContract();
}
```

Пример контейнера-исключения:

```
public class ExceptionBundle extends Exception {

    @NonNull
    private final Reason reason;

    @NonNull
    private final Bundle extras;

    public ExceptionBundle(@NonNull Reason reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
        this.extras = new Bundle();
    }

    @NonNull
    public Reason getReason() {
        return this.reason;
    }

    public void putString(@NonNull String key, @NonNull String value) {
        this.extras.putString(key, value);
    }

    public String getString(@NonNull String key) {
        return this.extras.getString(key);
    }
}
```

Пример контракта, который занимается записью данных в контейнер и чтением данных оттуда:

```
public class ValidationExceptionContract extends ContractAccessor {

    @NonNull
    private static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "MESSAGE";

    public ValidationExceptionContract() {

    }

    public String extractMessage(@NonNull ExceptionBundle error) {
        return error.getString(KEY_MESSAGE);
    }

    public void putMessage(@NonNull ExceptionBundle error, @NonNull String message) {
        error.putString(KEY_MESSAGE, message);
    }
}
```

Соответственно, в любом месте, где вам потребуется обработать одну ошибку, ее отлавливание осуществляется простой проверкой источника; в остальных же местах куда приятнее чем instanceof в 1м варианте, можно использовать switch-case по типам источников, в каждой ветви которого ивлекая данные через соответствующий контракт и выбирая дальнейшие действия.

Немножко об обработке:

Различные исключения нужно обрабатывать в различных местах в вашем приложении. Рассмотрим два типовых случая:

1. Необходимо уведомить пользователя о возникнувшем исключении (как в примере с предварительной валидацией полей). В данном случае требуется изменить UI в соответствии с данными в конкретном исключительном случае. Таким образом, исключение, возникшее при валидации требуется обрабатывать в presentation слое вашего приложения, чаще всего - в классе выполняющем роль Presenter
2. Необходимо осуществить некоторые действия в фоновом режиме, незаметно для пользователя, при возникновении исключения (например - повторить запрос к серверу). В зависимости от того, выделяете ли вы данное действие как элемент бизнес-логики вашего приложения, или же как штатную работу источников данных, вам требуется отлавливать соответствующие исключения соответственно в domain - слое содержащем бизнес-логику приложения -, либо в data - слое, отвечающем за работу со внешними источниками данных (окружении). В случае повторной отправки запроса это скорее всего будет ближе к data.

Comment: Спасибо большое, но я все равно не понимаю, в каком именно архитектурном слое должна обрабатываться ошибка... :( Вы написали "Соответственно, в любом месте, где вам потребуется обработать одну ошибку, ее отлавливание осуществляется простой проверкой источника", что значит "в любом месте"?

Comment: В случае, если вы должны осуществить какие-то действия,  связанные с UI, как в примере выше с валидацией, вам потребуется обрабатывать исключения в слое представления (в случае MVP - в Presenter). Если у вас, например, выскакивает источник - сеть Интернет - и вам нужно при отсутствии подключения попробовать повторить запрос, то это скорее бизнес-логика или работа, которую нужно выполнять в слое работы с данными. Различные исключения могут обрабатываться в различных местах.

Comment: Спасибо, большое! Добавьте это в ответ, и я одобрю ответ

Comment: дополнил, немножко подредактировав